# Flutter: Garbage Collection - How to check?

Tags: flutter

In Flutter, how can I check if I am releasing (dispose) everything correctly?

I am building an application and I have the feeling that the simulator is getting slower after a series of hot reloads.

Many thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Dart comes with a debugger called `Observatory`. It does a bit of everything you need. From CPU/Memory usage, to time spent on each functions. Even breakpoints and code coverage.

When running your flutter app, it's available by default on the localhost.

When running `flutter run` in the terminal, the port will be displayed. 
On vscode with `Dart code` extension, you'll need to use the command `Open Observatory timeline`.

[image]

Comment: @Rémi In my case it opens in web browser, and it doesn't update in real time after that. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @CopsOnRoad there's a "refresh" button on the top right

Comment: @RémiRousselet Yes, there is a button, I thought it would be realtime by itself. But seems like you need to do that from your end. I think Flutter inspector being realtime is better if you only care about FPS and memory.

Comment: Observatory is replaced with `DevTools` in the latest changes of Flutter